# LOZ Windwaker HD scene never ends

Tags: wii-u, zelda-wind-waker, zelda-wind-waker-hd

for some reason the LOZWW HD for WiiU when I get to the part at the beginning with the telescope aryll keeps asking "hey,what's that? playername! are you looking at the red postbox?", plays a chime and then a bloop as if the message was accepted then displays it again. no mater where I look and however long I spend looking in that direction it keeps doing that and none of the buttons except the control sticks work. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to zoom in all the way on the post box. The game is slightly picky about where you're looking too. Try zooming in and centering on the post box then work from there. The game won't proceed until it knows you're looking at the right spot

Comment: I zoom to 9x, it doesn't seem to go any further. I guess I could try wiggling the camera a bit to see if it can be centered better.

Comment: Try turning off aiming with motion controls, and focus on the postbox using the control stick. I had what's possibly the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to zoom in all the way into the mailbox for Aryll to notice.